# Passing Date Type from form into Repository in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I got problem passing date field type from form into `getRepository()` function in Symfony2. Assume that I've `tanggal` field with date type in form :

```
$builder->add('tanggal', 'date')
```

Then in controller that handle my request :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$tanggal = $form->get('tanggal');
```

I want to use that $tanggal field for criteria in `getRepository()` :

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:Attendance')->findOneBy(array('date' => $tanggal));
```

I got error like this :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1 UndefinedMethodException:
>   Attempted to call method "format" on class
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" in
>   C:\Sifony\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php
>   line 53.
>
> ```
> in C:\Sifony\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php
> ```
>
> line 53

If I do manual get like this :

```
$tanggal = new \DateTime($request->request->get('form')['tanggal']);
```

It's working fine with that code but I feel this is not quite right and bad practice. I think there is problem Date type in `getRepository()` with `handleRequest()`

I try to look into `C:\Sifony\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php` and seems the problem is no matter database field (doctrine) using date type or datetime type, the getRepository() class need DateTime type to work properly.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getDateFormatString()) : null;
}
```

Is there any way to convert date type from my form into DateTime or any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is ur getting object of Symfony\Component\Form\Form class.

Try to

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

and access date data from that variable.

Comment: I cant believe this. I think I've do this before. This is works like magic `$tanggal = $form->get('tanggal')->getData();` I have struggle with this almost 2 hours, maybe I'm really tired to figure this out. Thank you very much.